# Very basic form produces error so that page doesn't load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

A form is giving me problems so I've brought it down to the minimum to find out the cause. However, still loading the view produces the error below. Other views/pages all work without problems and if I remove the `form_for` line from the view then it loads the page correctly. But what's wrong with the `form_for` line (I even have a similar line with only a different url in another view, but I don't see how the url could be the cause of the problem...)?

> syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

I have in my controller:

```
def overview
  @user = User.find_by(username: params[:id])
end

def set_default
  #Nothing in this method yet
end
```

My view:

```
<h3>My overview</h3>
<%= form_for(@user, method: :post, url: set_default_path) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `do` in `form_for`. That's why you are getting that mentioned error. It should look like this:

```
<h3>My overview</h3>
<%= form_for(@user, method: :post, url: set_default_path) do |f|%>
<% end %>
```

For more information, see the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for).

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, I was a bit too eager skimming down my code ;-)